# css 3D transform elements disappear when perpendicular to viewer

Tags: html, css, 3d

html elements, being two dimensional,
have width & height but no thickness. not even a single pixel.

Therefore, when applying a 3D transform to an element, if its rotated perpendicularly to the viewer, it disappears.

Is there some property that can be set to remedy this situation?

It seems that the browsers should calculate elements as being 1 pixel thick if they are rotated in 3d.

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution applies to your case, due to the lack of details in your questions.

But, in a general way, you can do this adding a border to the element you are rotating.

There is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4L8Ht/1/. In this case, I've added a blue border (same color of the rotated div).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="rotateY r45deg"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="rotateY r90deg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-perspective: 400;
}

.rotateY {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #00f;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
}

.r45deg { -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg); }
.r90deg { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); }
```